# Writing to my CipherStream does not write to my ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, encryption, stream, aes

I'm trying to write a method in a testing environment to get it working before using it in my project. This method should take a string, turn it to bytes (using UTF-8 charset), run it through an AES `CipherOutputStream`, and then piece it back into a string (again with UTF-8).

My problem is that I don't really understand how the streams are working. I've seen examples of going from one file to another, but that's not what I want. Instead of a `FileOutputStream`, I have a `ByteArrayOutputStream`; however, it seems as if it's never even giving that stream anything, because when I read it, it's empty.

```
String encrypt(String raw)
{
    String encrypted = "";
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CipherOutputStream cipherStream = new CipherOutputStream(out, this.a);
    try
    {
        cipherStream.write(raw.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        encrypted += new String(out.toByteArray(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        out.close();
        cipherStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return encrypted;
}
```

Please ignore all the ugly generic catch blocks--I'll properly handle exceptions later. (No, I'm not getting any exceptions right now.)

I assumed the cipher stream would encrypt the bytes then write them to the stream provided in the constructor, but for some reason it's just sucking them in and never giving them back.

Any ideas as to where I'm screwing this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things are wrong:

1. You must close the cipher output stream before getting bytes out of the underlying byte array output stream. Otherwise, the doFinal() of the encryption operation is not performed.
2. Transforming arbitrary bytes into a String using UTF8 makes no sense. Either return a byte array, or encode the byte array using base64 to obtain a String. Every sequence of bytes is not a valid sequence of UTF-8 encoded characters.

.

```
byte[] encrypt(String raw) throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         CipherOutputStream cipherStream = new CipherOutputStream(out, this.a)) {
        cipherStream.write(raw.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        cipherStream.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Note though that using a CipherOutputStream is not really needed when all you want to encrypt is an in-memory byte array. A stream is useful when reading a long stream of bytes and encrypting them on the fly.

You could simply use

```
byte[] encrypted = this.a.doFinal(raw.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, I'm not actually going to be using the method that returns a string. I only did that so I could print it out and see it.